# After I changed MyEclipse directory,I can not start it.How can I do to make it well done without reinstalling it?

Tags: path, myeclipse

After I changed MyEclipse directory,I can not start it.
"D:\MyEclipse10" to "D:\Common_Tools\MyEclipse10".
then it has a problem like

```
"no jvm was found after search the following locations:D:\MyEclipse10"
```

So I change the file "myeclipse.ini" and make the right path of "jvm".Then the problem is gone whlie the next appear like this:
"java was started but returned exit code=13".
And the log is :

```
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:978)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:557)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

How can I do to make it well done without reinstalling it?(Or must reinstall?)
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the myeclipse.ini file again and make sure that ALL of the paths in there point to the correct location.
If that doesn't work, you will have to reinstall. If you have additional plug-ins, you'll need to reintall those afterwards. If you don't have any (or not many) additional plug-ins, it's not too big a deal to just reinstall. Delete the .pulse2.locator file in your home folder first, for full flexibility about where to install.

Comment: Thank you very much .The myeclipse.ini is not wrong,and I will reinstall.